# Add math variable into wordwrap

Tags: php, str-replace

I need to add a variable of `$y + 40` to each wrapping. I cannot seem to figure this out for the life of me. Does anyone else have a effective method?

NOTE: this is using the wordword wrap, not the while loop.

```
$y = 150; 
while(the_repeater_field('unordered_list')):

    $start = '<text y="'.$y + 40.'" x="172" class="bullet">&#8226;';
    $text = $start.wordwrap(get_sub_field('list_item'), 10, "</text>".$start, 0); ?>
    echo str_replace(array("<strong>","</strong>"), array("<tspan y='". $y ."' x='172' font-weight='bold'>","</tspan>"), $text); 

endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change ( " ) at evey php tag instead of (')

```
 $start = "<text y='".$y + 40.:' x='172' class='bullet'>&#8226;";
```

CMIIW